# GL_Triangles with Tessellation Shaders

Tags: opengl

When i am using Tessellation Shaders, do I have to pass from my CPU Program Patches rather then Triangles?.

```
    glDrawArrays(GL_PATCHES, 0, 3); //Works with Tess Shaders

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); //Works not with Tess Shaders
```

What is a Patch exactly to visualize it? Can it be a triangle which is being subdivided?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A patch is just a collection of points with no real intrinsic structure... your TCS and TES are what make sense out of them. Unlike `GL_TRIANGLES` (which is strictly defined by 3 vertices), `GL_PATCHES` has no pre-defined number of vertices per-patch. You set the number of vertices in a patch yourself with:

```c
glPatchParameteri ​(GL_PATCH_VERTICES​​, N);
// where N is some value less than GL_MAX_PATCH_VERTICES
```

Then, every `N`-many vertices drawn defines a new patch primitive.

Patches are really just a collection of control points for the evaluation of a surface. This is literally why there is an *optional* stage called `Tessellation Control Shader` that feeds data to a `Tessellation Evaluation Shader`. Without more details about the type of surface you are evaluating, about the only way to visualize them is as a point cloud (e.g. `GL_POINTS`).

### Update:

#### Assuming you are discussing a [Bézier surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_surface), then the control points can be visualized thus:

[image: Bezier Surface]

The red points are the control points (vertices in `GL_PATCHES`), the blue lines are artifical (just for the sake of visualization) and the black squares are the evaluated surface (result of a Tessellation Evaluation Shader). If you tried to visualize this before tessellation evaluation, then your patch would be nothing but red dots and you would have a heck of a time trying to make sense of them.

Comment: So A Patch would be an N-Gon ?

Comment: No, an N-Gon implies something about connectivity. The vertices in a patch are not really directly connected. The best way to illustrate this point is to show you a [***bézier surface***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_surface). They are control points, and during the evaluation of the curve many new vertices may be created... ***that*** is when you can start talking about polygons like triangles or quads. But before tessellation is evaluated, all you have are patches, no polygons.

Comment: How can you draw the blue lines in modern OpenGL?

Comment: To answer my question: use glDrawArrays or glDrawElements with GL_LINES to draw lines between two points, thus prepare the vertex data or better the vertex indices as: 0,1,1,2,2,3,3,0 to draw the quad(0,1,2,3).