# Tessellation Shaders

Tags: opengl, tesselation

I am trying to learn tessellation shaders in openGL 4.1. I understood most of the things. I have one question.

What is gl_InvocationID?

Can any body please explain in some easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `gl_InvocationID` has two current uses, but it represents the same concept in both.

In Geometry Shaders, you can have GL run your geometry shader multiple times per-primitive. This is useful in scenarios where you want to draw the same thing from several perspectives. Each time the shader runs on the same set of data, `gl_InvocationID` is incremented.

The common theme between Geometry and Tessellation Shaders is that each invocation shares the same input data. A Tessellation Control Shader can read every single vertex in the input patch primitive, and you actually need `gl_InvocationID` to make sense of which data point you are supposed to be processing.

#### This is why you generally see Tessellation Control Shaders written something like this:

```
gl_out [gl_InvocationID].gl_Position = gl_in [gl_InvocationID].gl_Position;
```

`gl_in` and `gl_out` are potentially very large arrays in Tessellation Control Shaders (equal in size to [`GL_PATCH_VERTICES`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glPatchParameter.xhtml)), and you have to know which vertex you are interested in.

Also, keep in mind that you are not allowed to write to any index other than `gl_out [gl_InvocationID]` from a Tessellation Control Shader. That property keeps invoking Tessellation Control Shaders in parallel sane (it avoids order dependencies and prevents overwriting data that a different invocation already wrote).

Comment: I may have neglected to point this out - your TCS runs (is invoked) `GL_PATCH_VERTICES`-many times for every patch you process.

Comment: Dear Andon, Can you please also let me know that what is meant by GL_MAX_PATCH_VERTICES

Comment: @MuhammadAwaisKhalid: `GL_**MAX**_PATCH_VERTICES`? That is the largest number of control points your implementation supports in a patch primitive. I have a description [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075462/gl-triangles-with-tessellation-shaders/24075672#24075672).

Comment: I want to render a surface using B-Splines and tessellation shader. I have control points over the surface. Can you suggest me some steps how to do it.?